# Process subclass can't run in windows

Tags: python, python-2.7

I'm running a program that starts a process with a queue sending information back and forth. I can't get a class (subclassed from Process) to start in windows (it works on linux). A simplified version of the code is:

```
from multiprocessing import Process, Queue

class Client( Process ):
    def __init__( self, q ):
        super( Client, self ).__init__()
        self._q = q

    def run( self ):
        self.startClient()

    def startClient( self ):
        self._q.put( 'abc' )

class Other( object ):
    def start( self ):
        self.q = Queue()
        self.client = Client( self.q )
        self.client.start()
```

Starting the process (client) doesn't cause the 'run' (and hence startClient) to be called.

I know a simple solution is to use the main entry point (if `__name__` == '`__main__`':), but this is part of a larger program and isn't accessed via that entry point.

Is there any other way to get this working on windows?

Comment: What code are you using to run the process?

Comment: What's in the main module of the larger program? Can it be imported without starting some lengthy work?

Comment: @BrenBarn:If you take 'Other' to be a larger class that does a bunch of processing (including data from the queue setup between them). The 'Other' class is one of many, in a larger system.

Comment: @Janne Karila: what would be the process, to import a main from another module into this one?

Comment: `multiprocessing` will import the main module, which means executing any code that is not protected by the `if __name__ == '__main__'`. Is there code that should not be executed in subprocesses?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the main module is not using `if __name__ == '__main__':` and you don't want to change it, create a new main module that imports the old main like this, and launch the app by running the new main:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    import main_module
```

Comment: Sry for the late response. It seems the problem was related to the dev environment we use, an in-house setup. But I'm pretty sure the solution you give is correct :).